# Implementing proximity search in positional inverted index nodejs

Tags: search, indexing, full-text-search, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I am building a positional inverted index from text, the index structure is: (suggest improvements, if any)

```
 {
     term: {
         documentID: {pageno:[positions], pageno:[positions]}, 
         documentID: {pageno:[positions]}
     }
 }
```

I want to implement a proximity search-
Proximity search :

> Queries of type X AND Y /3 or X Y /2 are called proximity queries. The expression means retrieve documents that contain both X and Y and 3 words or 2 words apart respectively

Reference - [Boolean Retrieval Model Using Inverted Index and Positional Index](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/boolean-retrieval-model-using-inverted-index-and-positional-index-2a9782bcec99)

I want to implement this in NodeJS for **2 or more** words. I am confused about how to implement this.

I thought of creating a search result object for each word from the index. This would have a structure like:

```
word :{document1: {page1:[positions], page2:[positions]}}
```

and then somehow compare the positions on every intersecting page for all the words and calculate the proximity.

For the search query `nodejs hello world`, the proximity in the string `hello extra words world more extra words nodejs` would be 5 - counting all extra words in between and summing them - regardless of order of the search words. Refer to this [Lucene Proximity Search for phrase with more than two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558195/lucene-proximity-search-for-phrase-with-more-than-two-words)

1. Is this an efficient index structure? If yes, how to compare the positions on every intersecting page for all the words?
2. If "jakarta apache lucene"~3, if this is the query and the text is 'jakarta jakarta apache lucene', will it match twice? - 3 being the max proximity allowed.

EDIT:

By doing a lot of things, I generated this for every document:

```
{
    pageno: [
        [positions of word 1],
        [positions of word 2],
        [positions of word n]
    ]
}
```

This makes sure to include only those pages which have all the words present.

For eg -

```
{
    1 : [
        [1, 5, 6],
        [2, 41],
        [3, 7, 11]
    ],
    2 : [
        [1, 5, 6],
        [2, 41],
        [3, 7, 11]
    ]
}
```

Now what I need to do is find the total number of occurrences of the query text on a particular page using the positions of query words mentioned in the array above such that difference between their positions is less than the proximity value.