# Find total number of occurrences in array of arrays at a particular cumulative distance

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am building a way to do proximity search in a positional inverted index -
[Implementing proximity search in positional inverted index nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581094/implementing-proximity-search-in-positional-inverted-index-nodejs). This is a sub-problem in that.

I have an array of arrays containing positions of different words on a page.

```
{
    pageno: [
        [positions of word 1],
        [positions of word 2],
        [positions of word n]
    ]
}
```

For eg -

```
{
    1 : [
        [1, 5, 6],
        [2, 41],
        [4, 7, 11]
    ],
    2 : [
        [1, 5, 6],
        [2, 41],
        [3, 7, 11]
    ]
}
```

I want to find, for each `pageNo`, the number of occurrences such that the sum of the differences between positions of words do not exceed a specified value (`proximity`).

If the value of `proximity` is 1, all the words shouldn't have more than 1 word between them. So a "Hello world nodejs" should match "Hello world in nodejs" as there is only one word in between - 'in'.
But, it won't match 'hello from world in nodejs' as there are total 2 words in between- 'from' and 'in'.

Note, that jumbled words are allowed.

How to do this in JavaScript? - I was trying to do something like [Finding matches between multiple JavaScript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37067050/10217754) but couldn't make the necessary changes to make it work here.

The expected output for the above case would be (proximity: 2):

```
{
    1 : 3,
    2 : 3
}
```

Page 1: (1,2,4)-Proximity (2-1 -1)+(4-2 -1)=1, (5,2,4)- Proximity (5-4 -1)+(4-2 -1)=1 and (6,2,4)

Page 2: (1,2,3), (5,2,3), (6,2,3)

Comment: What is the expected output for your example array?

Comment: @ITgoldman It will be a number, for each pageNo, the number of times the condition matches - 'ALL words are found within the specific proximity'

Comment: @ITgoldman I corrected the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use "cartesian product" function from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/3807365).
Then sort each of the result counting the maximal difference between items. Check that against proximity and increase count if legit.

Update: Corrected distance formula according to comments. Also `sort` here requires explicit conversion to numbers. (Why? let me know in the comments below)

```js
var input = {
  1: [
    [1, 5, 6],
    [2, 41],
    [4, 7, 11]
  ],
  2: [
    [1, 5, 6],
    [2, 41],
    [3, 7, 11]
  ]
}

function cartesianProduct(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.map(function(x) {
      return b.map(function(y) {
        return x.concat([y]);
      })
    }).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b)
    }, [])
  }, [
    []
  ])
}

function distance(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return +a - +b;
  });
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total += (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] - 1)
  }
  return total;
}

function count_index(arrs, proximity) {
  var product = cartesianProduct(arrs);
  var count = 0;
  product.forEach(function(series) {
    if (distance(series) <= proximity) {
      console.log("found: " + series)
      count++
    }
  })
  return count
}

var result = {}
var proximity = 2;
Object.entries(input).forEach(function([key, value]) {
  result[key] = count_index(value, proximity)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach. Just few corrections - sort in javascript is in place and converts to string first, hence numbers cannot be sorted directly - `arr.sort((a,b) => a>b);`

We don't need the max distance, we need to sum of all distances. And the distance between 2 and 1 is 0 - as there are no positions in between. Distance between 1 and 3 is 1 as there is a position (2) in between.

Comment: `sort` in javascript converts each element to a string and then compares them. Hence, the default sort function doesn't work for numbers. As "100" < "2".
Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000851/how-to-sort-numbers-correctly-with-array-sort